# Multiple down-values with exactly the same lefthand side

Tags: function-construction, variable-definitions, core-language, downvalues, conditional

I was working on an answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54765/3066), when I was sidetracked by what I bring up here.

I wanted a function, which when given a string representing a binary number, would convert the string to a list of digits. I wanted to reject any invalid strings and to return the function expression unevaluated an invalid string was rejected.

I had a lot of trouble debugging the function. My edits to the function body didn't seem have any effect. Finally, in desperation, I got to performing `Clear[bitsToDigits]` before making an edit. This allowed to complete my debugging, but left me very puzzled because I have come to expect edits which don't effect the first argument of a `SetDelayed` not to require clearing the function's identifier. In such cases, I have come to expect evaluating `SetDelayed` to replace the old down-value with the new one.

I decided to look at the down-values after making a second definition of now working function, but not to clear before evaluating it.

```
bitsToDigits[bitstr_String] :=
  With[{result =
    Module[{valid, bits = Characters[bitstr]},
      valid = StringFreeQ[bitstr, Except["0" | "1"]];
      If[valid, bits, False, False]]},
    result /; result =!= False]

bitsToDigits[bitstr_String] :=
  With[{result = 
          If[StringFreeQ[bitstr, Except["0" | "1"]], 
             Module[{bits = Characters[bitstr]}, bits], False, False]},
    result /; result =!= False]
```

I now looked at the down-values

```
DownValues[bitsToDigits]
```

To my horror, the result was

> ```
> {
>    HoldPattern[bitsToDigits[bitstr_String]] :> 
>      With[{result = 
>        Module[{valid, bits = Characters[bitstr]}, 
>          valid = StringFreeQ[bitstr, Except["0" | "1"]]; 
>          If[valid, bits, False, False]]}, 
>        result /; result =!= False], 
>    HoldPattern[bitsToDigits[bitstr_String]] :> 
>      With[{result = 
>              If[StringFreeQ[bitstr, Except["0" | "1"]], 
>                Module[{bits = Characters[bitstr]}, bits], False, False]}, 
>        result /; result =!= False]
>  }
> ```

The new version of my function will never be executed because the older definition will always match first.

This was totally unexpected. Should I have expected this? Is there something wrong with my definitions of `bitsToDigits`? If so, how should I fix them? Or have I found a bug?

I have verified that my problem occurs in both V9 and V10 running on OS X.

#### update

Mr.Wizard has answered my question as originally posted, but I would be keen to learn if there is a way to implement the behavior I want without the distressing side effect, which interferes with my ingrained code development habits.

Comment: `The new version of my function will never be executed because the older definition will always match first` it should really have kept only the last one? ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vboMh.png) yes, this is very strange.

Comment: @Nasser. I suspect it must involve my using `Condition`.

Comment: oh, I did not even see the `Condition` you had there, since it was at the bottom of the body, I never saw condition put there!

Comment: @Nasser `Condition` has very special behavior when used that way.  Please see the middle of this answer for an explanation in my own words: [(1852)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1852)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `Condition` is treated as part of the unique pattern of every assignment, even on the right-hand-side:

```
f := 1 /; foo
f := 2 /; bar

Definition[f]
```

> ```
> f := 1 /; foo
>
> f := 2 /; bar
> ```

You are using the notably unusual form:

> `lhs := Module[{vars}, rhs /; test]` allows local variables to be shared between `test` and `rhs`. You can use the same construction with `Block` and `With`. »

Since the body of the evaluation is part of the condition in this syntax it is logical that *Mathematica* treats this `Condition` RHS as a unique *black box*.  To do otherwise would greatly limit this mechanism.

For clarity your example can be stripped down to this:

```
ff[_] := With[{result = foo}, 1 /; result]
ff[_] := With[{result = bar}, 2 /; result]

Definition[ff]
```

> ```
> ff[_] := With[{result = foo}, 1 /; result]
>
> ff[_] := With[{result = bar}, 2 /; result]
> ```

That is two fully functional definitions for `ff` existing in parallel, the return value (or non-evaluation) determined by the values of global `foo` and `bar`.  Despite the fact that the *apparent* right-hand-side of each `/;` is `result` they are clearly different and behave accordingly.

---

Addressing your updated question and the request for a work-around, the first thing that comes to mind it to simply `Unset` your left-hand-side before creating a new definition.

This could be automated as follows:

```
Unprotect[SetDelayed];

SetDelayed[LHS_, RHS_] :=
  Block[{mod`autoUnset = True},
    Quiet @ Unset @ LHS;
    LHS := RHS
  ] /; ! TrueQ[mod`autoUnset]

Protect[SetDelayed];
```

Now:

```
ff[_] := With[{result = foo}, 1 /; result]
ff[_] := With[{result = bar}, 2 /; result]

Definition[ff]
```

> ```
> ff[_] := With[{result = bar}, 2 /; result]
> ```

Comment: I am satisfied that you have answered my question as originally posed. I have added an update requesting a work-around eliminating `Condition`. Can you update your answer to supply such a work-around?

Comment: @m_goldberg I'll have to think about that.  As I hoped to explain in my answer I think this is reasonable behavior but I also appreciate the desire to customize things to your own liking.  I ask however that you more clearly state your parameters.  Do you want to look *only* at the left-hand-side when replacing definitions?  Will this operation be done programmatically or does it need to only affect manual definition entry?

Comment: @m_goldberg Please take a look at my update and tell me what you think.

Comment: Your update looks interesting but beyond my understanding at first glance. I need to study it. What is ``mod`autoUnset`` by the way? I've never seen that before. Also, how safe is it (the whole redef of `Set`) for less than expert users such as myself.

Comment: @m_goldberg Start here: [(39711)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39711).  ``mod`autoUnset`` is an arbitrary non-localized Symbol; I figured sticking it in ``mod` `` is better than cluttering ``Global` ``.  This is not safe because it could affect all sorts of internal things that rely on exactly the behavior that you don't want.  Consider it a proof of concept.  If it superficially works as you wish I will instead create an "environment" function as Leonid often does, which can be used in `$Pre` to affect only manual input.  (Which is why I asked about that.)

Comment: BTW, I am now working with this improved version of my code: `bitStringToDigits[bitstr_String] := With[{result = If[StringFreeQ[bitstr, Except["0" | "1"]], ToExpression@Characters[bitstr], False, False]}, result /; result =!= False]`. I don't think that matters from your point of view, but in case I might be wrong, I that I should let you know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15717/discussion-between-m-goldberg-and-mr-wizard).