# How to draw timing diagram from a 0 and 1 string list (2)

Tags: graphics

I like ubpdqn's last edition & Mr Wizard's refactoring to my [last question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54765/how-to-draw-timing-diagram-from-a-0-and-1-string-list) very much. I inserted two `Reverse` just to make the diagrams and the strings match in order.

```
fun[str : {__String}] := 
 Module[{fs, n, timd}, 
  fs = Riffle[#, #]~Append~Last[#] & /@ ToExpression@Characters@str;
  n = Length@First@fs;
  timd = Reverse@fs~Append~PadLeft[{0}, n, {0, 1}];

  ListLinePlot[MapIndexed[#1 + 2 First@#2 - 2 &, timd], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 0, Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {Thread[{Range[1.5, n - 1.5, 2], Range[n/2]}], 
     Thread[{Range[0.5, 2 Length@timd, 2], 
       Join[Reverse@str, {"clock"}]}], None, None}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, n + 1}, Automatic}]]
```

[image]

And here, I managed to make the input strings rotate dynamically with the following code,
the problem is I failed to make the timing display rotates with the strings as well.
Pls help.

```
str2 = {"11000011", "00000011", "11100111"};
Dynamic[
 Refresh[str2 = {StringJoin[RotateRight[Characters[str2[[1]] ]]], 
    StringJoin[RotateRight[Characters[str2[[2]] ]]],
    StringJoin[RotateRight[Characters[str2[[3]] ]]]
    };
  Column[{str2[[1]], str2[[2]], str2[[3]]}], UpdateInterval -> 1
  ],
 TrackedSymbols -> {}
 ]
```

Comment: You may like [StringRotateRight](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringRotateRight.html) if you have V9 or later :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a small change in your function `fun` to allow options:

```
funB[str : {__String}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{fs, n, timd}, 
     fs = Riffle[#, #]~Append~Last[#] & /@ ToExpression@Characters@str;
     n = Length@First@fs;
     timd = Reverse@fs~Append~PadLeft[{0}, n, {0, 1}];
     ListLinePlot[MapIndexed[#1 + 2 First@#2 - 2 &, timd], 
                 InterpolationOrder -> 0, Frame -> True, 
                 FrameTicks -> {Thread[{Range[1.5, n - 1.5, 2], Range[n/2]}], 
                                Thread[{Range[0.5, 2 Length@timd, 2], 
                                Join[Reverse@str, {"clock"}]}], None, None}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, n + 1}, Automatic}, opts]]
```

Then, just insert `funB[str2]` inside `Refresh`:

```
  str2 = {"11000011", "00000011", "11100111"};

  Dynamic[Refresh[str2 = StringRotateRight /@ str2;
          Row[{Column[str2] // Style[#, 36] &, funB[str2, ImageSize -> 500]}, 
               Alignment -> Center], 
         UpdateInterval -> 1], TrackedSymbols -> {}]
```

[image]

**Update:** You can also use `Clock` and use the third argument of `Clock` to control the number of repetitions:

```
 Dynamic[{Clock[{1, 1}, 2, 1]; str2 = StringRotateRight /@ str2;
     Row[{Column[str2] // Style[#, 36] &, funB[str2, ImageSize -> 500]}, 
     Alignment -> Center]}, TrackedSymbols -> {}]
```

Comment: Is there a way to stop the program? Mousedown can pause the program, "Alt+." & "Alt+," can't stop the execution.

Comment: You can toggle  `Dynamic Updating Enabled` in the `Evaluation` menu.

Comment: @user16069, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.